# go tool pprof: no matches found for regexp

Tags: go, pprof, heap-profiling

cmd:go tool pprof -alloc_objects main.test memprofile.out

```
File: main.test
Type: alloc_objects
Time: Aug 16, 2023 at 4:33pm (CST)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 17323653, 99.81% of 17356430 total
Dropped 1 node (cum \<= 86782)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 15
flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
14374456 82.82% 82.82%   14374456 82.82%  awdb.(*awdbReader).readDecode
1048624  6.04% 88.86%    1966142 11.33%  strconv.syntaxError (inline)
983055  5.66% 94.52%     983055  5.66%  net.IPv4 (inline)
917518  5.29% 99.81%     917518  5.29%  strconv.cloneString (inline)
(pprof) list readDecode
Total: 17356430
ROUTINE ======================== awdb-go/awdb.(awdbReader).readDecode in /root/workspace/*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/xxx/main.go
14374456   40982478 (flat, cum) 236.12% of Total
.          .    209:func (r \*awdbReader) readDecode(offset uint) (interface{}, uint, error) {
.          .    210:   dataType := intTypeData(r.buffer\[offset\])
.          .    211:   newOffset := offset + 1
.          .    212:   switch dataType {
.          .    213:   case \_Arrary:
1070445   14374456    214:           return r.awDecodeArrary(newOffset)
.          .    215:   case \_Pointer:
.   13304011    216:           return r.awDecodePointer(newOffset)
.          .    217:   case \_String:
13304011   13304011    218:           return r.awDecodeString(newOffset)
.          .    219:   case \_LongString:
.          .    220:           return r.awDecodeLString(newOffset)
.          .    221:   case \_Uint:
.          .    222:           return r.awDecodeUint(newOffset)
.          .    223:   case \_Int:
(pprof) list awDecodeString
no matches found for regexp: awDecodeString
(pprof)
```

Calling relation:awDecodeArrary->awDecodePointer->awDecodeString

'list awDecodeString' output the memory usage is displayed

Comment: why 'list awDecodeString' output "no matches found for regexp"?